# Problems with circular dependency

Tags: c++, visual-c++, module

I have tried to solve the problems related to circular dependency in some files I have made following that structure:

A.h

```
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"
#include "D.h"

namespace NS {

class B;
class C;
class D;

class A {

/* ... */

    A(const A& a) {};

    A(const B& a) {};
    A(const C& a) {};
    A(const D& a) {};

/* ... */
};

}; // NS END
```

B.h

```
#include "A.h"
#include "C.h"
#include "D.h"

namespace NS {

class A;
class C;
class D;

class B {

/* ... */

    B(const B& a) {};

    B(const A& a) {};
    B(const C& a) {};
    B(const D& a) {};

/* ... */
};

}; // NS END
```

C.h

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
#include "D.h"

namespace NS {

class A;
class B;
class D;

class C {

/* ... */

    C(const C& a) {};

    C(const A& a) {};
    C(const B& a) {};
    C(const D& a) {};

/* ... */
};

}; // NS END
```

D.h

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"

namespace NS {

class A;
class B;
class C;

class D {

/* ... */

    D(const D& a) {};

    D(const A& a) {};
    D(const B& a) {};
    D(const C& a) {};

/* ... */
};

}; // NS END
```

Whatever I try I have some errors from the constructors taking as argument classes in other files, even putting the declaration ahead, seems like it take it the declaration as declaration and definition, and ignore the real definition that is in another file. How could I solve that?

NOTE: I have define guard in each file, just I didnt put it here

Comment: I don't see any include guards.  Please show some real code.

Comment: Why do you forward declare classes *and* include the headers as well?

Comment: I didnt put the guard for make is shorter here, but there are in all files, real code doesn't contribute with anything here, only make it messy, scheme is the same

Comment: a. you don't need to forward declare classes you are including. b. circular dependencies, however possible, are usually a bad idea. You can usually get what you wanted initially by inheriting from parent classes and adding virtual methods.

Comment: I don't know, I doubt which one of both must be, and which not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you remove all the #includes in the headers and put them in the source files, everything should compile.

You don't need the includes since you have forward declarations which is sufficient in this case since you only use const references to the forward declared classes. (note: previous statements only hold if your sample code mimics your actual code).

You can also add a seperate header forward.h containing the declarations, instead of repeating yourself everywhere:

```
namesapce NS
{
  class A;
  class B;
  class C;
  class D;
}
```

Now make A.h, B.h etc `#include forward.h` and you do not need the forward declarations in each header anymore.

Answer (score 0):

forward declarations!
If you are not using classes methods, forward declarations can help you to disentangle the dependencies.

http://www-subatech.in2p3.fr/~photons/subatech/soft/carnac/CPP-INC-1.shtml

Answer (score 0):

In addition, it is always a good idea to add #include guards as follows:

#ifndef _INCLUDED_A_H
 #define _INCLUDED_A_H

.... < here are the normal contents of your header file > ....

#endif

But the main thing is, as stijn pointed out, when you have forward declarations you don't need to include the full definitions as well.